# SystemVerilog equivalent of VHDL record ports

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

My VHDL entity has those two unidirectional record ports:

```
user2regs     : in user2regs_t;
regs2user     : out regs2user_t
```

Which are defined in a package as follows:

```
type user2regs_t is record
    status_value : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
end record;

type regs2user_t is record
    control_led : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
end record;
```

How do I implement the same ports/interface in a synthesizable SystemVerilog module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are structures in SystemVerilog.

```
typedef struct {
   logic [31:0] status_value;
   } user2regs_t

typedef struct {
   logic [3:0] control_led;
} regs2user_t;

module mod ( input user2regs_t user2regs,
             output regs2user_t regs2user);
```

Comment: Hi @dave_59, thanks for your answer. Is that how you would implement that in actual RTL code or would you rather use SystemVerilog interfaces instead?

Comment: That was the direct translation. Using structures in SV can help you get stronger types (See [my paper](http://go.mentor.com/4gub7) on it. The choice on whether to use an interface is a different question. That depends on how re-usable the interface needs to be.